# Quickly generate email aliases from the Windows system tray

Tags: email, spam-prevention

I would like to be able to generate email address aliases which forward to my main email address really quickly and easily.  Basically, I'm sick of spam, and I have found the best way to deal with it is to give all companies separate email addresses - that way, I can track who sold my email address on.

The ideal solution would be some kind of app which would let me create email aliases very quickly from, say, the system tray, as I'm entering a sign-up form online.

Does anyone know of a piece of software that will let me do this? I realise it would have to be tied to some online service, so happy to pay.

thanks
Kris

Comment: What about a Gmail address with [+ aliases](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=12096)? You can just use `your.name+company@gmail.com` and emails sent to that will automatically arrive at `your.name@gmail.com`.

Comment: Does it have to be the system tray exactly? There are free(!) online services offer two-click solutions using extensions or popups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although technically possible, it wont work well.  Most of the free email services out there try to prevent people from making large amounts of email addresses easily.  Why?  To stop spammers.

The best solution to your problem would be to create your own mail server.  That way you have free rein on creating all the email addresses you want.